# REACT-How to increment value in an object without deconstructors

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to increment one of these values without deconstructing the values.

How can I do it?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'    
    function App()
    {
    const [values,setValues]=useState({
      counter:0,
      counter1:0
    })
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>{values.counter}</h1>
          <button onClick={()=>setValues(prev=>({...prev,[values.counter]:prev.counter+1}))}>add</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default App
```

Comment: By "without deconstructuring" you mean without spliting your state in 2 distincts values ? I would be the simpliest solution.

Comment: The code above isn't working i am trying to increment it with still values.counter, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in your code:

```
setValues(prev=> ({...prev, [values.counter]: prev.counter+1 }))}
```

it should be:

```
setValues(prev=> ({...prev, counter: prev.counter+1 }))}
```

Otherwise you get a state of:

```
0: 1,
counter: 0,
counter1: 0
```

and you will keep adding stuff like: 1: 2, 2: 3, ....

Besides that, I can see at least three ways of doing this safer:

**Method 1:**

```
const [values, dispatch] = useReducer(
  (state, { type, field }) => {
    switch(type) {
      case 'INCREMENT': return { ...state, [field]: (state[field] || 0) + 1 }
      default: throw new Error('Unhandled case in values reducer')
    }
  },
  { counter: 0, counter1: 0 }
)
```

**Usage:**

```
onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT', field: 'counter' })}
```

**Method 2:**

```
const [values, setValues] = useReducer(
  (oldState, newState) => ({ ...oldState, ...newState }),
  { counter: 0, counter1: 0 }
)
```

**Usage:**

```
onClick={() => setValues({ counter: values.counter + 1 })}
```

**Method 3** (Enhanced Method 2):

```
const [values, setValues] = useReducer(
  (oldState, newState) => {
    return typeof newState === 'function'
      ? { ...oldState,...newState(oldState) }
      : { ...oldState, ...newState }
  },
  { counter: 0, counter1: 0 }
)
```

Usage:

```
onClick={() => setValues(prev => ({ counter: prev.counter + 1 }))}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a possible option for you, you could also simply split your state in two :

```
function App()
{
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>{values.counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(prev => counter + 1)}>add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

[image: Edit counter button click]